# Where is a good place to learn HTML 5 specification

Tags: html

I learned HTML in 1997. I haven't revisited it in all those years, focusing my efforts on server side languages that have been in use at the companies paying my salary (Cold Fusion, classic ASP, ASP.NET).

Now that HTML 5 is here, I've decided to rethink the paradigm and learn the standard way to code HTML and CSS.

Currently the site I manage is built to work in quirks mode. It makes extensive use of nested tables and has no doctype declaration. I've noticed that simply adding an html 5 doctype to the pages causes the page to not render correctly.

Can someone suggest a site or book or other material which will help me eliminate my reliance on tables and make the use of CSS make sense? I'm not looking to become a master overnight, but managing a site with thousands of pages means I better know what I'm doing before I dive into any redesign.

Mike

Comment: The specs: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/

Comment: More important after reading about it is knowing if it is available on your target platform: http://caniuse.com/

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I've found [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/) to be the best resource on this, of course, after the  [W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/).

Remember that HTML5 is *still a work in progress*, it's not a standard as of yet and it won't be for a long time so everything you learn about it now is subject to change. In reality, though, most modern browsers are supporting [most of it's features](http://html5test.com/) already it so it's better to start now.

And about your tables vs. CSS dilemma, I'd sugest reading on [this discussion about the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html).

Comment: Mark Pilgrim has not written anything in that for years so I'm not sure how up-to-date it can be. For sure, much is not in there.

Comment: @Rob That's true, it's not exactly up-to-date. But for someone who's just learning, it probably gives the best and most thorough insight to HTML5 and not that "technical". But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

[MDN's resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) is what I found most useful.
The introductions are well written. Docs are comprehensive and clearly marks new features introduced by HTML5 and those deprecated.

Comment: By far one of the best references and instructional sites around. It also includes instructions for new people but caters to the professional.

Answer (score 2):

- http://www.html5doctor.com, http://www.html5demos.com and http://www.html5rocks.com offer HTML5 demos and great insights into using HTML5.
- http://www.html5please.com and http://www.caniuse.com offer insight into the availability of an HTML5 feature in browsers and suggests fallbacks if possible.
- https://developer.mozilla.org - Mozilla Developer Network has some extremely valuable insights into the specification and usage of it.
- http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec, the official spec. It's actually understable! :-)

Also, for a book I'd suggest ["The Modern Web" by Peter Gasston](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781593274870.do). It came out a couple of months ago and contains a lot of the latest specs (flexible boxes, for one). I also like the general ideas of the book (how the web should be used, e.g. seperating HTML/CSS/JS) and I found the writing style to be quite pleasant.

Answer (score -2):

W3 Schools is a great resource for HTML and other web languages.

http://www.w3schools.com

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @bas Ignore the w3fools nit-picking. Walk into any professional development environment and see how many have w3schoools open in a tab for reference. While there are errors and oversights, it's just fine for most purposes, though it's hard to beat MDN.